# LIRC on Raspberry pi has not been initialized error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lirc

I'm trying to get LIRC functioning within my code. I've created some test code but I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ir_remote.py", line 5, in <module>
    config = lirc.nextcode()
  File "lirc.pyx", line 183, in lirc.nextcode (lirc/lirc.c:2983)
  File "lirc.pyx", line 217, in lirc._is_init_or_error (lirc/lirc.c:3472)
lirc.InitError: lirc has not been initialised.
```

The code I created:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lirc, time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

config = lirc.nextcode()

sockid = lirc.init(blocking = False)

if config == 'KEY_DOWN':
    print 'Red OFF'
if config == 'KEY_UP':
    print 'Light Red'
if config == 'KEY_LEFT':
    print 'Red'
if config == 'KEY_RIGHT':
    print 'Green OFF'
if config == 'KEY_OK':
    print 'Light Green'
if config == 'KEY_1':
    print 'Green'
if config == 'KEY_2':
    print 'Blue OFF'
if config == 'KEY_3':
    print 'Light Blue'
if config == 'KEY_4':
    print 'BLUE'
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `lirc`, but looking at your code and the error message, it seemas like you need to call `lirc.init` before you can call `lirc.nextcode`.

Comment: Maybe next time you will read the error message before jumping onto SO?

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap these two lines around:

```
config = lirc.nextcode()
sockid = lirc.init(blocking = False)
```

Because you need to initialize `lirc` before starting to use it.
Should look like this:

```
sockid = lirc.init(blocking = False)
config = lirc.nextcode()
```

At least according to all their documentation, just noticed @larsks said the same thing and I gotta say it too. I've never worked with this library before, but checking the [documentation](https://github.com/tompreston/python-lirc#use) and the error message, it's a reasonable assumption.